# Error running pod install - Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner`

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

Hello I am not able to solve this problem with Cocoapods anyone can help me is the first time I am using this import-  **import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.Dart';** and not what might be wrong.

(I’m using android studio on mac)

ERROR:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              1,3s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_vlc_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_vlc_player/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_vlc_player":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_vlc_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_vlc_player/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_vlc_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_vlc_player/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open *[YourProject]/ios/Podfile* and remove the `#` sign from `platform :ios, '9.0'` and try `flutter run`.
If it doesn't work increase the version number for example to 10.0

Answer (score 5):

Setting Podfile to the version needed for package would work.

For instance, if you want to use webview_cookie_manager 2.0.0, you shoud set minimum version for iOS to 11.0 as given on its spec page.

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager

So on Podfile, setting platform ios value as below works.

```
 platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

1. run sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
2. then go to ios folder with cd ios
3. and run the command arch -x86_64 pod install

https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/01/error-running-pod-install-how-to-solve.html